# What is the maximum cache size in Node JS?

Tags: node.js

In my application I'm using caching, to store the array values. I wanted to know what is the maximum cache size the Node JS can store? (if it exceeds that then it will blow up)

Comment: 2048 (or 4096, depending on version) by default, but configurable.

Comment: @goodvibration is there any command to check that?

Comment: `node --max-old-space-size=4096`